# Proof of an inequality in a triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

The magnitudes of the sides of $\Delta$$ABC$ are $a=BC$,$b=AC$ and $c=AB$, with $c\le b\le a$.Through interior point $P$ and the vertices $A,B,C$,lines are drawb meeting the opposite sides at $X,Y$,and $Z$, respectively.
Prove that $AX+BY+CZ<2a+b$.

**My attempt:**

I applied Stewart's theorem and by that i got the following equations:

$c^2 \cdot XC+b^2 \cdot BX=a(AX^2+BX \cdot XC)$

$c^2 \cdot YC +a^2 \cdot AY =b(BY^2+AY \cdot YC)$

$a^2 \cdot AZ +b^2 \cdot BZ=c(CZ^2 +AZ \cdot BZ)$

After that i get stuck, i don't know what to do...i tried to use law of sines to

express $XC,BX,YC,AY,AZ,BZ $in terms of $a,b,c$ so i have three clean equations

expressing $AX,BY,CZ$ in terms of the lengths of the triangle but it wasn't kind of usefull as it just replaces $XC,BX,..$ with expressions involving sines of angles adjacents to $AX,BY,CZ$ and that just makes the problem more messy...

Last thought i had was to use the various formulas of area of triangle and i am still on this way but so far i didnt get anything usefull...

**Question:**
Could you  give me some hints on what's the best strategy to adopt in this problem,and in general some strategy euristic on this kind of problems where i have to prove some inequality ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to convince yourself that $AX<b$, $BY<a$ and $CZ<a$

Comment: @Kaladin I've made the case  that $a=b=c$ and by that using the first equation i wrote i get$ AX^2=b^2-AX \cdot XC$ which implies $AX<b$,is that way correct ?btw thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is putting @’Kaladin 's suggestion into practice.

[image]

Let the perpendicular bisector of XC cut AX produced at R such that RC = RX.

Then, in $⊿CAR, AC + RC \gt AR = AX + RX$. This means $AC \gt AX$. That is, $AX \lt b$.

Do the same thing to the other two sides.

Result follows.

Answer (score 1):

You took the long way. Simply, if $ABC$ is an acute-angled triangle and $X$ is some point on the $BC$-side, the length of $AX$ is $\leq \max(AC,AB)$. It follows that: 
$$AX+BY+CZ\leq b+a+a = 2a+b.$$

However, this side-problem is really interesting:

> Given an acute-angle triangle $ABC$, for which points $P$ inside $ABC$ the sum of the lengths of the cevians through $P$ is minimized?