# Bisector of angle lies between height and median of triangle at a vertex

Tags: geometry

I want to prove that internal bisector of angle A is ( always lies) between height and median lines of triangle ABC.

[Traingle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xzgtl.jpg)

Is it possible to help me?
Thanks.

Comment: It seems like you need $AB\neq AC$. If so, you can assume $AB<AC$.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can you explain more? If $AB < AC$, Then what happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Among the three, the altitude (AH) is definitely the shortest because it is the perpendicular distance of A from BC.

In your figure, we can assume that AC > AB.

By angle bisector theorem, AC : AB = CD : DB. This means CD > DB.

Also, from the fact that M is the midpoint of BC, we can say M is on the right of D.

If this is so, we have a triangle ABM with AD being an internal line of it. Then see my work in  [Proof of an inequality in a triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1477941/proof-of-an-inequality-in-a-triangle/1478102#1478102)

Comment: thanks for answer. I understand that M is on the right of D But Why D is on right of H. I see our prove But I can't understand their relationship.

Comment: If the median is always longer than bisector( comparing to common height) their ratio should be always less than 1. But plotting on same axes gives sometimes the ratio > 1 . So it is puzzling a bit... Plot[ {1, (a + b)/(4 a b) Sec[CC/2] Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 - 2 a b Cos[CC]]}, {CC, 0, Pi }]

Comment: wow. It's very hard for me. I am student and I don't know about what you do in plot. is it possible to explain more?

Comment: @Amin Regarding why D is on the right side of H, I have that explained via the angle bisector theorem. The trick is we have assumed AC > AB. If it is the otherwise, (i.e. AC < AB), then D will be on the left of H.

Answer (score 3):

> $\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$ **Proof without words :**

---

[image]

---

Well, not quite. :-$)$ In order to grasp things intuitively, first fix two things: the size of the angle 
 $($in green$)$, and that of the angle bisector $($the segment connecting the two yellow dots$)$. Keeping 
 the foot of the bisector fixed $($lower yellow dot$)$, we let the other two vertices of the triangle slide 
 freely along the two lines which determine the given angle. Thus we have the two pairs of red 
 and blue points. The former determine an isosceles triangle, where all three lines $($median, bi– 
 sector, and height$)$ coincide. In the latter case, by moving one vertex higher, $($and thereby closer 
 to the upper tip of the triangle, determining the height to fall on the right half of the figure$)$, the 
 other one is inevitably lowered, causing the position of the median's foot to descend, by stretch– 
 ing the length of the left portion of the triangle's base $($uniting the lower-left blue dot to the foot 
 of the bisector$)$, while simultaneously shrinking its right side $($uniting the foot of the bisector to 
 the upper-right blue dot$)$.